# How to include optional space in Grep statement

Tags: grep

I have some log files that I'm grepping through which contain entries in the following form

```
foo($abc) - sometext
foo ($xyz) - moretext
baz($qux) - moartext
```

I'm looking to use grep that would output the first two lines as matches, i.e.

```
foo($abc)
foo ($xyz)
```

I've tried the following grep statement

`grep 'foo(\$' log.txt`

which outputs the first match, but I tried to include an optional space, and neither return:

`grep 'foo\s?(\$' log.txt`

I'm using the optional space incorrectly, but I'm unsure how

Comment: `grep -E 'foo\s?\(\$' log.txt` will work in a GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a POSIX BRE regex and `foo\s?(\$` matches `foo`, a whitespace, a **literal `?`**, a literal `(` and a literal `$`.

You can use

```sh
grep -E 'foo\s?\(\$' log.txt
```

Here, `-E` makes the pattern POSIX ERE, and thus it now matches `foo`, then an optional whitespace, and a `($` substring.

See an online demo:

```sh
s='foo($abc) - sometext
foo ($xyz) - moretext
baz($qux) - moartext'
grep -E 'foo\s?\(\$' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
foo($abc) - sometext
foo ($xyz) - moretext
```

You may still use a more universal syntax like

```sh
grep 'foo[[:space:]]\{0,1\}(\$' log.txt
```

It is a POSIX BRE regex matching `foo`, one or zero whitespaces, and then `($` substring.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the query slightly and use `*` instead of `?`:

```bash
grep 'foo *(\$' log.txt
```

or use a literal whitespace and escape `?`:

```bash
grep 'foo \?(\$' log.txt
```

Both solutions would work with GNU, busybox and FreeBSD grep.